# Splash screen with logo in fade in + move up

Tags: move, fade, splash-screen

I'm really a newbie of jquery... but I'd like to put an effect on my website, hoping you could help me.

My intent is to have a splash screen with the logo (http://oi49.tinypic.com/34ss55v.jpg) appearing in fade in, then (after 2 seconds) move up the logo and let the rest of the website appear.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `fadeIn()` method to show the splash screen.
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Afterwards, you would call `fadeOut()` or `slideUp()` to hide the graphic.

- http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
- http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Try this (minimal) example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="splash" style="display:none;"><img src="http://oi49.tinypic.com/34ss55v.jpg"/></div>

    <script>
      // Slowly fade in image (5 seconds) and then slide it up (2 seconds).
      $().ready(function() {
        $("#splash").fadeIn(5000).slideUp(2000);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks man, you made my day! now the problem is to put the rest of the website under the logo :D http://www.nicolobertoncin.com/test/prova.html